# Smallest Von Neumann universe to contain countably many nested parenthesis

Tags: set-theory

If the Von Neumann universe for some limit ordinal $\lambda$,is $V_\lambda=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda,\beta=\mu+1}\mathcal{P}(V_\mu)$ which is the first $\lambda$ such that $\underbrace{\{\{…\}\}}_{\omega \text{ times}}\in V_\lambda$ or $\in \mathcal{P}(V_{\lambda-1}) $ ? I can’t see how a set with anything but a finite number of parenthesis could ever be produced.

Comment: Can you give a formal definition of this set with countably infinitely many nested parentheses? I suspect there is no such set.

Comment: Any successful definition will be equivalent to a set $x$ such that $x=\{x\}$, which contradicts the axiom of regularity. So ZF will prove "there is no such $x$", and since ZF proves every set has a rank, it proves "there is no $\lambda$ containing $x$".

Comment: By the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), there is no such $\lambda$.